# JavaFX image rendering takes too much memory while webcam stream which causes app crashing

Tags: java, javafx, memory, webcam

I have a problem with RAM while rendering image from webcam (using sarxos-webcam) on JavaFX thread which causes application crashes.
Stack used:

```
Java 8 / JavaFX 8
Sarxos webcam capture 0.3.12
Camera driver: OpenIMAJ 0.3.12 (currently the only tested driver which provide like 30 FPS on tablet with IMX175)
Windows 10
```

When I start webcam stream the memory demand significally increases from like 400MB to over 2GB RAM  and starting/stopping camera for a few times, but when camera is then turned off and I change the JavaFX scene, the memory doesn't drop - so app gets crashing after e.g. an hour (the camera module is just a part of this app).

Here's the code which causes the problem:

```java
private void startCameraStream() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        if (!webcam.isOpen()) {
            webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD.getSize());
            webcam.open(false);
        }
        Task<Void> task = getImageTask();
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.start();
        image.imageProperty().bind(imageProperty);
    });
}

private Task<Void> getImageTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void call() {
            while (!pauseWebcam) {
                try {
                    if ((grabbedImage = webcam.getImage()) != null) {
                        Platform.runLater(() -> {
                            Image mainImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(grabbedImage, null);
                            imageProperty.set(mainImage);
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    grabbedImage.flush();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

As you can see I tried methods like "flush" inside or outside the JavaFX thread but it doesn't help. The memory demand stops at some level but the rest of the application becomes unusable.

Is there any way to prevent that or clear the memory after scene changed?

I have also created the minimal gist example to show the problem on working application:
https://gist.github.com/AreXe/2e5dd350ef4076126cc62156e0cb98fa

Individual files:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>camera</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.sarxos</groupId>
            <artifactId>webcam-capture-driver-openimaj</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

src\main\java\Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setScene(createStartScene());
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public Scene createStartScene() throws IOException {
        return new Scene(loadStartPane());
    }

    private Pane loadStartPane() throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("camera.fxml"));
        Pane startPane = loader.load();
        loader.getController();
        return startPane;
    }
}
```

src\main\java\CameraController.java

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.WebcamResolution;
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.ds.openimaj.OpenImajDriver;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class CameraController implements Initializable {

    static {
        Webcam.setDriver(new OpenImajDriver());
    }

    @FXML
    StackPane rootPane;
    @FXML
    ImageView image;
    private Webcam webcam;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage;
    private static BooleanProperty stopWebcam = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        stopWebcam.setValue(false);
        image.setFitWidth(rootPane.getWidth() - 20d);
        setCameraStopListener();
    }

    @FXML
    private void cameraStart() {
        stopWebcam.setValue(false);
        startCameraStream();
    }

    @FXML
    private void cameraStop() {
        stopWebcam.setValue(true);
    }

    private void startCameraStream() {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
            if (!webcam.isOpen()) {
                webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.HD.getSize());
                webcam.open(false);
            }
            Task<Void> task = getImageTask();
            Thread th = new Thread(task);
            th.start();
            image.imageProperty().bind(imageProperty);
        });
    }

    private Task<Void> getImageTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                while (!stopWebcam.get()) {
                    try {
                        if ((grabbedImage = webcam.getImage()) != null) {
                            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                                Image mainImage = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(grabbedImage, null);
                                imageProperty.set(mainImage);
                            });
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        grabbedImage.flush();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    private void setCameraStopListener() {
        stopWebcam.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue && webcam != null && webcam.isOpen()) {
                webcam.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

src\main\resources\camera.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane fx:id="rootPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="840.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="CameraController">
    <children>
        <ImageView fx:id="image" fitHeight="480.0" fitWidth="768.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER" />
      <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0" StackPane.alignment="BOTTOM_CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button onAction="#cameraStart" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Start" />
            <Button onAction="#cameraStop" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="100.0" text="Stop" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
    </children>
</StackPane>
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. here (external links will fade away :)

Comment: How does `webcam.getImage()` work? When does it return null? Is it throttled? Because if it returns a non-null value every invocation, and isn't throttled, then you're posting a new `Runnable` to the FX thread at the rate of a full-throttle `while` loop (i.e. as fast as the CPU allows). This should be overwhelming the FX thread with `Runnable` instances. The problem is made worse if `getImage()` returns a new `BufferedImage` instance each invocation, because that could result in multiple copies of multiple images being in memory simultaneously.

Comment: you did read the referenced help page, didn't you ;) Mind the __M__, please (strip it down ..)

Comment: sorry @kleopatra I posted more files to show that the problem occurs even changing the scene, now i added only the code that start/stop camera
@Slaw i found that code in library example, with little changes: https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-javafx-fxml/src/main/java/WebCamPreviewController.java 
the method ``webcam.getImage()`` "captures BufferedImage from webcam and returns null if webcam is closed or has been already disposed by JVM", so images gets rendering every "tick" but it's not cleaned from memory, don't know how to do that

Comment: I haven't tested anything myself, but I have serious doubts about the full-throttle `while` loop. Can you try using an `AnimationTimer` (instead of `Task`) and grabbing an image in the `#handle(long)` method to see if that helps the problem? Note that an `AnimationTimer` is executed on the FX thread once per frame, making both the calls to `Platform#runLater(Runnable)` and the `while` loop unnecessary.

Comment: Ok I tried replacing the code with AnimationTimer to something like:
``new AnimationTimer() { ... handle(long now) {imageProperty.set(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(webcam.getImage(), null))}}`` with setting the time to update: ``if (now - lastUpdate > 30_000_000)``
but the memory is still growing even when I call ``imageProperty.unbind()`` or ``imageProperty.set(null)``, there must be some other way to do that, I'm new to JavaFX concurrency

Comment: How are you measuring memory consumption? Increasing to some maximum and then the "memory demand stops at some level" sounds like the normal behavior of a Java application: it just fills up the heap to some maximum, and then the GC will kick in. Have you used a profiler on this?

Comment: @James_D I checked the results on VirtualVM and: when app starts it takes ~140MB RAM (byte[] and int[] takes 4-6MB) then after camera start it grows to over 700MB RAM and byte[] takes 90% of resources (3mln B+). When i disabled camera images from rendering (camera still working) then RAM consumption doesn't grow. And what this tells me? How can i achieve situation to stop this byte[] from growing so application doesn't crash? Tablets used has only 4/8GB RAM so this is huge problem. For comparision, native Windows camera application takes only 50MB RAM. Does anyone know any tips?